# How to give Static numbers to GPIOs of each I2C expander?

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

I have connected three I2C based GPIO expanders with my CPU board. GPIO511 to GPIO496 populated for Expander1, GPIO495 to GPIO480 populated for Expander2, and GPIO479 to GPIO464 are populated for Expander3.

e.g

- IO expander1 : GPIO511 to GPIO496
- IO expander2 : GPIO495 to GPIO480
- IO expander3 : GPIO479 to GPIO464

I have seen those GPIO at location : `/sys/class/gpio/`

All the things are working fine and I am able to operate each GPIO.

But, when I remove IO Expander IC 2 from the I2C bus, Linux gives the GPIO ID [GPIO495 to GPIO480] from Expander2 to Expander3(As shown in case 2 in attachment). Due to this, my other functionality gets affected.

So, is there any way to give and initialize from fix GPIO_Base for each I2C expander, in simple words I want to give fix GPIO group to each IO expander?

The IO expander I am using is PCA9555, and Linux kernel Version is 4.9.x+fslc (4.9.44-fslc+g8f876e153b25)

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this problem?

Thank you

[I2C_GPIO_Expander_Problem_Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahjCX.png)

Comment: device numbers are assigned consecutively on every boot.  You may be able be able to match a physical device address such as pci under /sys.

Comment: @stark, it’s not guaranteed and basically no need to follow exact number.

Comment: Why do you need that? Global GPIO numbering should not be used at all. Hint (in case you can’t perform without it): you need to dynamically derive this information based on the unique device reference in the sysfs. Your expander has I2C address and I2C host controller has its own reference in the system.